# GWT, Eclipse Plugin how to rename project along with .gwt.xml file? Am getting error when try to do so

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, refactoring, classpath

I've spent a while searching on this and nothing that I find seems relevant specifically to my issue. I am making RPC calls so I wanted to change the path to one of my web services.

It was something like `mytestproject` and wanted to change it to `finalprojectname`

I went to the `mytestproject.gwt.xml` file and changed 
`<module rename-to='mytestproject'>` to `<module rename-to='finalprojectname'>`

I then ran it through and got an error that `[ERROR] Unable to find 'org/ediscovery/gwt/mytestproject.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?`

I then changed `mytestproject.gwt.xml` to `finalprojectname.gwt.xml` but still got the same result.

I've looked through every possible file and can't find why it thinks the project is still named `mytestproject`. I have cleaned and rebuilt the project, etc but still the same. I am still fairly new to Java so maybe I am missing something obvious. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can offer any advice. Thanks

Comment: What is the build tool you are using(maven or ant)? Have you renamed on hosted html/jsp file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To rename a project from "mytestproject" to "finalprojectname":

1. In your .gwt.xml file, change
   `rename-to="mytestproject"` to
   `rename-to="finalprojectname"`.
2. In your .html file, change
   `src="mytestproject/mytestproject.nocache.js"` to
   `src="finalprojectname/finalprojectname.nocache.js"` (note the double replacement!)
3. In your web.xml file, adjust paths like
   `<url-pattern>/mytestproject/greet</url-pattern>` to
   `<url-pattern>/finalprojectname/greet</url-pattern>`

Anything else (like renaming packages, or renaming the .gwt.xml file) is optional.

If you do choose to rename your .gwt.xml file afterwards, then it's necessary to delete the output folder (war/finalprojectname). In Eclipse, also delete your old Run Configuration, and then create a new one by using "Run As > Web Application".

Comment: I came here for the same reason, and in my case the only problem was to delete the stored "Run configuration", as other steps I did as described above.